# Are colored persuasion options random?

Tags: fallout-4

If I see a yellow/orange/red persuasion option, does it have a random chance of succeeding/failing based on my stats or will it always succeed/fail depending on my stats?

In other words, will save/reloading affect the conversation in any way?

Comment: Another good question would be: do my stats affect the color I get?

Comment: @Nolonar that's a great point, would be good to know as well!

Comment: I kind of assumed color represented a "percentage range". (like 67-100% is yellow, 34-66% is orange, 0-33% is red, or whatever. I made those up) Obviously that's just my assumption. Would be interesting to see a concrete answer though.

Comment: The tutorial pop up the first time you get a persuasion option specifically says that the color tells you how likely you are to succeed.  That said, I've failed a yellow and passed an orange at this point.  Next time I see one near a quck save I'll do a few trials.

Comment: @Nolonar, in game tutorial specifically tells you that it does. Speech is effected by your Charisma, with special cases impacted by Perks.

Comment: Started a new Charisma 10 character, options still show the exact same colors as with a Charisma 3 character, but this time I have yet to fail any speech check at level 15 while the CHA 3 character was barely able to pass some yellow checks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you can indeed save scum conversation options.  After failing a yellow speech check, I reloaded and passed it the second time.